# How can I unset a value within a nested array of objects? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How do you unset a value like treatment, likes or disease?
I tried

```
db.myCollection.update({first_name:"QQQ"},{$unset:{"history.treatment":1}});
```

It finds the match, but it doesn't unset it. What am I doing wrong?

myCollection:

```
 { first_name: "QQQ",
last_name: "BBBB",

"history" : [
                {
                        "disease" : [
                                "X",
                                "Y",
                                "Z"
                        ],
                        "treatment" : "No treatment",
                        "likes" : "french fries"
                }
        ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Treatement` is nested inside `history array` so you need to use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#positional-update-all) positional operator

```
db.myCollection.update({first_name:"QQQ"},{$unset:{"history.$[].treatment":1}});
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes! I saw the array, but I really had no idea how to access it! Thanks again!